# Testing the SQL Server driver existence

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

If I have to test for the driver, Is it the correct way of doing it:

```
try {
    // Loading the Driver

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
}                                                                                           
catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
    return false;                                                                                         
}
```

I keep on getting an error on the line `return false` that boolean cannot be converted to integer. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is it really required to perform this step in Netbeans as I already have the jar file in my library?

Thanks

Comment: Your method need to return an int I guess. Change it with public boolean myMethod()

Comment: Can you please tell us that what is the return type of your method and what is your method returning.
You have to return true - when there is no exception.

Comment: I am just putting an additional check to see whether my driver is loading successfully or not and if I mention return as true or false, I keep on getting error that I just mentioned. Why do you think that's I should use true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the method is `integer` and you are trying to return `boolean` value in the catch block as ::

```
return false;
```

`Solution :` Change the return type of the method as `boolean` or return `integer` value from catch.

Comment: I changed it to `return 0` and error disappeared. Thanks !